# Convert string with HTML tags in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to pass a string with HTML tags without changing the Razor code?

Scenario (current code):

```
string msg = "<a href='http://www.google.com/html/'>Google</a>";
```

OUTPUT:

```
<a href='http://www.google.com/html/'>Google</a> on the page.
```

GOAL result:

Link to Google without changing the code "@msg".

Comment: try `@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(msg));`

Comment: That's changing the Razor code though but thanks.

Comment: @Amogh: There's no need to decode first. In fact, unless, you *know* you're dealing with an encoded HTML string, this is likely to result in invalid HTML, as things like `&amp;`, which should be output exactly as is to the page, will end up as `&` which is invalid.

Answer (score 18):

try @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(msg));

Answer (score 4):

You can try with

```
HtmlString msg = new HtmlString("<a href='http://www.google.com/html/'>Google</a>");
```

instead of

```
string msg = "<a href='http://www.google.com/html/'>Google</a>";
```

Comment: I apologized, I need to clarify further. Since I cannot change and Razor code, is there a way to construct the content of the string so that it converts its content into HTML tags/elements.

Comment: You can use `HtmlString` in the controller, so you don't touch the razor code.

Comment: Sorry this should be last add for me - no code change besides string "msg" content. No Razor or any .NET/MVC code changes.

The string value is retrieved from external source (database).

Answer (score 4):

Hey You can edit your razor code as:

```
@{

     HtmlString msg = new HtmlString("Hello <br> Hello Again");
     <p style="text-align:justify;"> @msg  </p>
 }
```

It's simple